# How to extract the text from the selected item on the listView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a listview with some items. I would like to get the text from the selected item.

Here is my list adapter and the onItemClickListener:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Country>(
            this,R.layout.list_black_text,R.id.list_content, values));


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
??????
    }});
        }
```

Could you tell me please how to get the String from the selected item.

the method ((TextView) view).getText() does not work, i have a

```
ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
```

I have found the solution, maybe somebody will need it:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Country>(
            this,R.layout.list_black_text,R.id.list_content, values));

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
            String text = textView.getText().toString(); 
            System.out.println("Choosen Country = : " + text);

    }});
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use this:

```
String selectedFromList = (String) (lv.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

Whatever the datatype you are having in your list, cast accordingly.

Hope it will help. :)

Comment: Nice and simple Answer ! =)

Comment: If you have just strings being put in to your adapter then you should have no problem doing the above, just cast it as a string to avoid any errors. String alloy = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

Comment: Edit: 
`String selectedFromList = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);`

Comment: @AliObeid edited as per your suggestion. @ ColossalChris

Answer (score 17):

For this you need to write the following:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
        String text = lv.get(position).toString().trim();
        System.out.println("Chosen Country = : " + text);

}});
```

Answer (score 6):

The other answers look good, but I thought `I'd wrap everything` up into one complete answer.

There are `multiple ways` to achieve this and it also depends on whether you are getting text from `simple listView` or from `Custom ListView(with custom_list_item.xml).`

**For Simple ListView**

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        String text = lv.get(position).tostring().trim();//first method 
        final String text = ((TextView)view).getText();// second method
}});
```

**For Custom ListView**

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
//where list_content is the id of TextView in listview_item.xml

}});
```

**Problem with others Answers**

`@Android Killer` string Casting is missing.

`@Rishi` doesn't give detail about using R.id.list_content

Comment: why is "get" in red?

Comment: @LUKER you need to use `lv.getItemAtPosition(position)` instead

Answer (score 3):

Hello I'm using a CustomListView with Registered Context Menu. In this case the way to access a item inside a custom list row will be:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add:
                TextView textView = (TextView) info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.yourItem);
                String text = textView.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Where R.id.yourItem is the textView inside the custom Row

PS: It's my first post, Hope it helps ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's for future reference for anyone that stumbles on this. 
In my case I had a custom adapter class, with type as a POJO class I had. Also the items I wanted to pass to the adapter and display in my `ListView` where of the `util.List` class.

I successfully passed the data to the ListView, but also wanted to get the text of the currently selected.

**Eg:** the data I passed was a list of schools that a lecturer taught at, so he had to select the particular school he wanted to work with at that time, and on logging in I wanted to pass an intent to a new `Activity` with the current school the lecturer had selected.

Thus my ListView *onClick()*:

```
private void loginSuccess() {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    if (mySchoolsList.size() > 1) {
        schoolsListView = new ListView(MainActivity.this);
        schoolsArrayAdapter = new SchoolListAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mySchoolsList);
        schoolsListView.setAdapter(schoolsArrayAdapter);

        dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(schoolsListView);
        dialog.setTitle("Welcome " + staff.getFullName());
        dialog.show();


        schoolsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //the .getName() is accessed from the School POJO class.
                String schoolName = schoolsArrayAdapter.getItem(position).getName();
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NavMainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("sentIntent", schoolName);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    } else {
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NavMainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("sentIntent", recieveName);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Hope this saves someone someday, because all the solutions here didn't work for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

**It will definitly works!Hope you Satisfied!**

```
ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String text = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a List to populate the ListView in your onItemClick() method.

```
String s = list.get(position);
```

You need to be able to access this list within the inner class

Comment: Unfortunetly, I am using a database query to populate my list.
I have found the solution and edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

try doing it by this, insert it into onItemClickListener, i am not sure what does your Country class look like:

```
String s = values.get(position).getCountryName();
Log.e("LISTVIEW", "selected item text = "+s);

  or

String s = values.get(position).toString();
Log.e("LISTVIEW", "selected item text = "+s);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onItemClick(**AdapterView**<?> parent, View view, 
                                            int position, long id) {

 }
```

See the `AdapterView`.....--->>>the class

Only need to do this :

```
  TextView selectedText=(TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

See...you get the `TextView` directly

Comment: and this can use in Fragment

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av,
                                View view, int position, long l) {
            String text = String.valueOf(myListView.getItemAtPosition(position));

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as that

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text1);
            TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text2);

            String txt_1 = ""+text1.getText().toString().trim();
            String txt_2 = ""+text2.getText().toString().trim();

           //Other_Related_Work

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simplest way:

**list_content.xml**

```
 <TextView
    <!-- rest of the code -->
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:onClick="get_content"  <!-- Just add this -->
    />
```

**MainActivity**

```
public void get_content(View view){

    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.content);
    System.out.println("Text is: "+textView.getText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I had tried some solutions here but they hadn't worked. Hope this helps.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myFamily);

    listViewDemo.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listViewDemo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //String nameSelectedfromList = arrayAdapter.getItem(position).toString();
            String nameSelectedfromList = listViewDemo.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            Log.i("Clicked Item", nameSelectedfromList);

        }
    });
```