# How to retrieve the clicked string from a listview using OnItemClick?

Tags: android, string, listview, onitemclicklistener

I've got some problem here. It looks simple and i keep searching for its solution. Unfortunately, i cant find anything. This is my problem.... What i'm trying to do is to get the string showed in the listview from an On item click method.

This is my listview :

```
- lol
- hi
- waw
```

When i click "lol" i want to get the "lol" string.....

What should i put in my code here?  :

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
 {
    // Intent newI = new Intent(this,PDetail.class); 
     Intent newI = new Intent (Create.this, PDetail.class);
     //String sd = ((() arg1).getText()).toString();
     //newI.putExtra("x", arg2);
     startActivity (newI);
    // db.getList(arg3);

 }});
```

Comment: You should post the code that actually populates the ListView

Comment: What type of adapters are you using? is it a custom adapter

Comment: i already know how to do it..... @ user2012,njzk2,karan23 already give me the answer what i need. But, thank for your attention.

Comment: multiple ways to achieve ListView Itemtext http://stackoverflow.com/a/28479593/3496570

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
     {
         String data=(String)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);


     }});
```

`data` contains your clicked position's data. Do what ever you want to do with that.

Comment: i'll have many input.... not just that three. i cant define them like that one by one..... i need something more flexibel and universal

Comment: what's with the 3 items ?

Answer (score 6):

`arg0` is your `AdapterView`, typically a `ListView`. `arg2` is the position in the `ListView`. You can get the items from your Adapter :

```
Object item = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
```

Depending on the type of your object in your adapter, a trivial solution is:

```
String value = item.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks, i appreciated your reply.

Answer (score 2):

The `arg1` parameter of your listener is the clicked item's view.

Assuming that the items of your `ListView` are `TextViews` you can try:

```
String itemText = ((TextView) arg1).getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

use String val = (String)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin use this:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener{ parent, view, position, id ->
        println("Item : " +  (view as TextView).text)
    }
```

This only works if you inflated your adapter with just a `TextView` otherwise instead of casting it to TextView you should get your TextView by doing something like

```
view.findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id)
```